# Running Flask with Flask_Login on Apache2 causes Webpage Login Issues

Tags: apache, flask, cookies, flask-login, linode

I'm out of ideas. When I run my Flask Website locally, everything works fine. Two users can use my website using two different browsers at the same time and everything just... works. Flask's Flask_Login deals with all the session cookies and current_users perfectly.

But, it all goes crazy when I push my build to the Apache2 production server. When an Administrator logs in, it seems that everyone else is considered to be that Administrator.

It is almost as if there is a duplication of cookies... or confusion about who the 'current_user' is.

My server is using Apache2 and I have mod-wsgi-py3 installed.

I followed this tutorial (https://youtu.be/w0QDAg85Oow) to push my Flask App to my Production Apache server.

Help?

Instead of pictures and code, I made a video to explain the issue: https://youtu.be/sho3oC5WpOQ

Comment: I just tried NGINX with GUNICORN and I got the same thing... but slower. omg - it is sooo slow.

Comment: I just pushed a 'session' blog tutorial (https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-sessions) to my Apache2/mod-wsgi and it worked flawlessly.

I'm thinking that there is nothing wrong with my current Apache2/mod-wsgi setup... and everything wrong with Flask_Login.

But, it has sooo much functionality that I don't want to implement myself!

Comment: A'ight, sooo... I'm not sure what is wrong with Flask-Login... but, I got rid of it and configured everything with my own Sessions (from flask import session) and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

A'ight, sooo... I'm not sure what is wrong with Flask-Login... but, I got rid of it and configured everything with my own Sessions (from flask import session) and everything works now.

This blog tutorial led me in the right direction:
https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-sessions